# MDM Spyware "Microsoft Company Portal" was installed on my business phone. Can I still use "Onion Browser" without them seeing what URI I am visiting?

Tags: ios

> [Can I run Tor Browser on an iOS device?](https://support.torproject.org/tormobile/tormobile-3/)
>
> We recommend an iOS app called Onion Browser, which is open source,
> uses Tor routing, and is developed by someone who works closely with
> the Tor Project. However, Apple requires browsers on iOS to use
> something called Webkit, which prevents Onion Browser from having the
> same privacy protections as Tor Browser.

MDM Spyware "Microsoft Company Portal" (was called Intune) was installed on my business phone. Can I still use "Onion Browser" without them seeing what URI I am visiting?

Answer (score 1):

A compromised system cannot be trusted overall.

A factory reset of the mobile phone can possibly improve the situation somewhat.